# Counterpart response for "übergeben"?

Tags: verb-usage

I am writing to a company that will hand over the apartment to me on day X (dass wir uns freuen, Ihnen die Wohnung am 30.12 übergeben zu können) . How to say ' Can I receive/take over the apartment on day Y?'
I am not even sure I am using the correct English verb but I hope you got the meaning.

Can I use (übernehmen) ?

Comment: It's not really a _"Gegenteil"_, hence I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking whether you can use *übernehmen* as a reciprocal of *übergeben* when speaking of appartments. Short answer:

Yes, you can.

> > Ich würde die Wohnung gerne am 5. Januar übernehmen.

is a perfectly good sentence. Slightly more usual/boilerplate would perhaps be:

> > Könnten Sie mir die Wohnung auch am 5. Januar übergeben?

and a bit more twisted, but still in common use:

> > Könnte ich die Wohnung auch am 5. Januar übergeben bekommen?

Generally the variations with *übergeben* will be perceived as a bit more polite, because they emphasize the other side's active position. (It is more polite to wait them give you something than ignore their action and take it.)